# Binding to directive attributes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create a draggable div and bind to it's location so that I can use that elsewhere. I need multiple draggable elements. So far I have created a 'dragable' attribute directive and can drag the element around the page as I need, I set the initial location with 'x' and 'y' attributes.

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div dragable x="50" y="50" style="...."></div>
    <p>
        x: {{x_loc}}<br/>
        y: {{y_loc}}
    </p>
<body>
```

The problem is when I try to add bind 'x' and 'y' to variables in the myCtrl scope

```
<div dragable x="{{x_loc}}" y="{{y_loc}}" style="...."></div>
```

This produces a generic invalid expression error. My directive looks like this:

```
app.directive("dragable", function($document) {
    dragable = {};

    dragable.restrict = 'A',
    dragable.link = function(scope, element, attrs) {

        element.css({
            top: scope.y + 'px',
            left: scope.x + 'px'
        });

        function select(evt) {
            ...           // get initial conditions 
            $document.on('mousemove',move);
            $document.on('mouseup',deselect);
        };

        function move(evt){
            ...          //do some error checking then
                         //update the element location
        };

        function deselect(evt){
            $document.unbind('mousemove',move);
            $document.unbind('mouseup',deselect);
        };        

        $document.on('mousedown', select);
    };
    dragable.scope = {
        x: "=",
        y: "=",
    };

    return dragable;
});
```

Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're doing a 2 way binding in your directive then you shouldn't be using an expression in your attributes. Just `<div dragable x="x_loc" y="y_loc"></div>` will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div dragable x="x_loc" y="y_loc" style="...."></div>
```

instead of

```
<div dragable x="{{x_loc}}" y="{{y_loc}}" style="...."></div>
```

because of

```
 dragable.scope = {
    x: "=",
    y: "=",
};
```

if you use  `x: "@"`     `x="{{x_loc}}"` will works

https://jsfiddle.net/1x0bxncp/1/

Answer (score 0):

I think there is problem with dragable.scope = {}.

- **One way binding**

  Use `{{}}` brackets in  attribute. In scope use  `x: "@x_loc"`
- **Two way binding**

  Use value from scope without brackets. In scope use  `y: "=y_loc"`

  You can ommit names here `x: "=x_loc"` if they **same**. Like this `x: "="`

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove the brackets from the scope properties  `<div dragable x="x_loc" y="y_loc" style="...."></div>`

Also you need to add `position:absolute` to your CSS style

[you can see it here](http://jsfiddle.net/n8ywaqzk/)